# How to get fist elemenent using local-name() in XPATH?

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<xyy:UP xmlns:xyy="urn:com" xmlns:xyx="urn:com" xmlns:xzx="urn:com">
<xyx:ITM>
<xzx:PID>ABCDEFGH</xzx:PID>
</xyx:ITM>
<xyx:ITM>
<xzx:PID>IJKLMNOP</xzx:PID>
</xyx:ITM>
</xyy:UP>
```

I tried follow xpath to get second 'PID' tag , which is having text node IJKLMNOP , but it wont return any.

```
//*[local-name()='PID'][1]
```

But it will list all the PID if I use follow

```
//*[local-name()='PID']
```

can any body drag me out of this plz

Comment: `//*[local-name()='PID'][1]` should return all 1st children `PID` elements, which are 2 in your sample document. If you only want the 2nd one, you can use parentheses: `(//*[local-name()='PID'])[2]` (remember XPath positions start at 1, not 0)

Comment: This particular wrinkle is spelled out in the [XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev): "NOTE: The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are the first para children of their parents."

Answer (score 4):

`//*[local-name()='PID'][1]` should return all 1st children PID elements, which are 2 in your sample document.

If you only want the 2nd one, you can use parentheses:

```
(//*[local-name()='PID'])[2]
```

(remember XPath positions start at 1, not 0)